# Process substitution (not command substitution) in Ruby

Tags: ruby

In bash, zsh, ksh88, ksh93 and similar shells, one can trivially generate a filename (which, as appropriate to the platform, is implemented as either a `/dev/fd` entry or a named pipe) in which a given piece of code is executed in a subshell.

I'm interested in doing the same thing in a Ruby interpreter -- executing a subprocess with one of its arguments a filename which, when read, will stream the output of code run in either the present Ruby interpreter or a subprocess of same.

Content is security-sensitive, so writing to temporary files is not ideal.

---

The equivalent code in bash:

```
./run-program --password-file=<(printf '%s' "$password")
```

...when run, will (on Linux or another platform with `/dev/fd/`) invoke something like:

```
./run-program --password-file=/dev/fd/5
```

...where `/dev/fd/5` can be read from (exactly once, being a stream) to retrieve the result of expanding `$password`.

---

What's the best approach to implementing the same calling convention in Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IO.popen` does the same thing as does `>()` or `<()` in the shell--it creates an unnamed, unidirectional pipe to which you can either read or write.

```
fd=IO.popen("echo hi") #"r"--reading by default
fd.read 
   #=>"hi\n"
   #Read from the file object
#OR access via the filesystem representation of the filedescriptor
File.read("/dev/fd/#{fd.fileno}")
   #This is just how linux works (note in Linux, each process sees `/dev/fd/` differently--it's actually the open filedescriptors a process has)
```

Basically, I think you'll want to use unamed pipes for this. Another common patter is to create pipe pairs with `IO.pipe`, fork off a child process, and since forking shares file descriptors, your child and parent process will be basically connected via that pipe pair of which you can have as many as you want.

Comment: Hmm. `IO.popen("-") { |f| f.puts(password) }` might be what I'm looking for here. An answer that holds up on OS X or other platforms without `/dev/fd` would be _ideal_, but this may very well be good enough.

Comment: I don't know about OS X, but these are all just wrappers around POSIX standardized C functions for IPC with pipes, so this stuff might be portable.

Comment: It's `/dev/fd` -- functionality not specified by POSIX -- where I'm concerned about portability, in particular. That said, it appears that current OS X has adopted it.

Comment: To be clear why `IO.popen("echo hi")` isn't a good fit precisely as-given, by the way -- keep in mind that I'm passing around password content; putting it on the command line of a shell isn't exactly secure, as argv arrays are public to anything running on a system. Once I have a working/tested variant using `IO.popen("-")`, I'll post here (and, with your permission, edit it into your answer).

Answer (score 0):

The basic answer will likely be building something out of Ruby's [`Kernel#spawn`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html#method-i-spawn) method. This will allow you to start another process and control which file objects the sub-processes uses for input and output.

Note that handling this can be tricky; it'll be helpful to have a good Unix application programming reference handy. Ruby is really just putting a thin wrapper around some of the low-level Unix/C API's.

Comment: Indeed -- that it's tricky is why there'd be value to having a canonical, peer-reviewed answer, which is why I'm asking this here before trying my own hand. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the password to the `cat` program using `IO.popen`.

```rb
# open a pipe to `cat`
# the argument is a one-element array to force it
# to run the program directly instead of through a shell
fd = IO.popen(['cat'], 'r+')
# write the password through the pipe
fd.print('password')
# finish writing
fd.close_write

fd.read #=> 'password'
# or
File.read("/dev/fd/#{fd.fileno}") #=> 'password'

fd.close
```